# For-loop condition mechanic for Pyramid code

Tags: c#

```
for (int row = 0; row < 5; row++)
{
    // PRINTS CORRECT NUMBER OF SPACES
    for (int space = 0; space < 5 - row - 1; space++) 
    {
        Console.Write(" ");
    }

    // PRINTS CORRECT NUMBER OF STARS
    for (int star = 0; star < row * 2 + 1; star++)
    {
        Console.Write("*");
    }

    // JUMPS ONTO NEXT LINE AFTER EVERY ITERATION OF THE FIRST LOOP
    Console.WriteLine();
}
```

How do the conditions "5 - row - 1", and "row * 2 + 1" work in this code?

Comment: Have you tried drawing the Pyramid first on the paper?

Comment: `5 - row - 1` is the same as `4 - row`.

Comment: So you just want an explanation of the code? Try drawing the pyramid (as @Am_I_Helpful suggested) and then try stepping through the code yourself line by line with a piece of graph paper. Hint: For the first row you need 4 spaces (5 - 0 - 1) and then 1 stars (0 * 2 + 1). For the next row you need 3 spaces (5 - 1 - 1) and 3 (1*2+1) stars...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all about noticing patterns in a pyramid. The comment for the first for loop says that it is printing the correct number of spaces before the actual pyramid (i.e. the asterisks).

Let's look at how many spaces there are at each level:

```
    *      level 0 - 4 spaces
   ***     level 1 - 3 spaces
  *****    level 2 - 2 spaces
 *******   level 3 - 1 space
*********  level 4 - 0 spaces
```

Notice how as the level number increases, the number of spaces decreases? They are inversely proportional. What would be a function that maps the level number `n` into the number of spaces? It would be

```
 f(n) = 4 - n
```

Or more generally,

```
f(n) = k - n - 1
```

where `k` is the number of levels.

This is why we wrote `5 - row - 1`. It maps `row` (i.e. `n`) into the number of spaces that should be printed!

The same goes for the second for loop, which figures out how many asterisks should be printed.

```
    *      level 0 - 1 asterisks
   ***     level 1 - 3 asterisks
  *****    level 2 - 5 asterisks
 *******   level 3 - 7 asterisk
*********  level 4 - 9 asterisks
```

This time the pattern is even simpler. It is just an arithmetic sequence. The function that maps the level number into the number of asterisks is

```
f(n) = 2 * n + 1
```

This explains the `2 * row + 1` in the second for loop.